# CURL POST with file - not working on Windows

Tags: php, windows, curl, file-upload, mamp

I have a php script that sends a file via cURL, to a remote location.

This works great on a Mac.

On Windows w/ MAMP (I am stuck with this at present), no request reaches the remote server.

If I take away the CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS parameter, the request is sent, however without my data (obviously). This tells me that cURL is loaded ok, and is able to send a request.

What I can't work out, is what is causing this to do nothing when CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS is included (as per the code below) - no errors (that I am aware of).

Here is the code that I am running:

```
function getCurlValue($filename, $contentType, $postname)
{
    if (function_exists('curl_file_create')) {
        return curl_file_create($filename, $contentType, $postname);
    }

    // Use the old style if using an older version of PHP
    $value = "@{$this->filename};filename=" . $postname;
    if ($contentType) {
        $value .= ';type=' . $contentType;
    }

    return $value;
}

$filename = 'c:\path\to\file\test.txt';
$cfile = getCurlValue($filename,'text/plain','test.txt');

$data = array('updateFile' => $cfile);

$ch = curl_init();
$options = array(CURLOPT_URL => 'http://url/to/my/service',
             CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
             CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT => true, //Request header
             CURLOPT_HEADER => true, //Return header
             CURLOPT_FAILONERROR => true,
             CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
             CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
             CURLOPT_POST => true,
             CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data
            );

curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$header_info = curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT);
$header_size = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
$header = substr($result, 0, $header_size);
$body = substr($result, $header_size);
curl_close($ch);
```

I have checked for cURL errors, of which there are none thrown.

Any thoughts would be most appreciated.

Thanks,

Nathan

Comment: check log files. it might have some info.

Comment: I have checked every log file that I can think of, and can't find a thing unfortunately.

Comment: In the beginning, put error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: I've added that, and still nothing. Any specific log file I should be focussing on? Thanks

Comment: apache error log and php error log(if enabled, else only apache). and also try `c:\\path\\to\\file\\test.txt` and `c:/path/to/file/test.txt`

Answer (score 0):

This issue appears to have resolved itself. All is now working, with no changes on my part.

Must have been something at the server end....